# (MySQL) Finding the first, second, ...., nth movie directed by a group of directors

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

There's a table titled "movies". [The table can be found here](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/filtering_sorting_query_results). (Please scroll down to the bottom of the page to see the table).

I want to find the list of first movies directed by each director in the list.

I've written the following query

```
SELECT director, title AS first_movie, MIN(year) AS year FROM movies GROUP BY director;
```

I did get the desired results but I'm wondering if there's any better way to do this.

Same way I want to find the list of second movies directed by all the directors in the list. How do i do it?

And finally, is there a general way to arrive at the list of nth movie directed by all the directors in the list?

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/99245/170408

Comment: The "first movie by each director" is simpler than the stuff in the "dup" Question.  See the tag I added.  Or read here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max